# Huge number of vertices and faces within a simple model

Tags: mesh, vertices, faces

I started using Blender and I love it.

My first project is to model a house. In total I ended up with 98 objects. Mainly walls, simple furniture and ceilings. I mainly used boxes, moved faces or extruded them.

Now I see that the count of vertices is 354357 and faces 364860. Even if I estimate that by mistake the walls have in average worst case 32 faces I end up with about 3000 faces.
I tried to merge vertices and see them counting down one by one. But there seem to be some generic failure I made.

Do textures add a huge number of vertices and faces or is there any other mistake which could cause such huge numbers of elements?

Hope someone has an idea what the issue is and how I can resolve it. Unfortunately I can't describe it in a better or more detailed way. Thanks in advance.

Think I found it. I created a door handle which counts 726 vents, 1419 edges and 695 faces. This multiplied by the number of handles used could end up with the big number. Maybe that helps others as well.

[image: Model screen shot]

[image: door handle]

Comment: Hi Steph. I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it. There's no need to include any texture files as they won't affect the geometry of your objects at all.

Comment: It seems only you see your 3d scene, so only you can figure this out. Nobody knows what or how you modelled. It's impossible to answer this question with provided information. You should edit it and form it in another way providing all the needed information if you want to get any meaningful help.

Comment: You are probably using a lot the boolean modifier to make holes, which can cause ngons

Comment: Wow this answers are fast. @John, just saw my file got a size of 688 MB too big to upload.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I agree it's a vage description and maybe not to be answered remote.

Comment: @Emir I added some 6 doors and 3 windows with boolean modifier.

Comment: @Steph, what you tell us doesn't mean much. At least [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/301837/edit) the question and add some screenshots.

Comment: Making holes with boolean could cause some issues, and make Ngons, which creates more vertices and edges, you should check some videos on how to make holes without boolean to have a cleaner topology

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys I added a screenshot. But it only shows the scene. I don't see what could cause such a big number of vertices or why the model got so big. For me it looks pretty simple.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Looks like I found the issue. I added another screenshot showing a door handle I created. It has a huge number of elements. I'll try to reduce their number. With the finding I'm able to search far a solution. Many thanks that you all tried to help!

Comment: I usually end up with around 1 to 6 millions of polygons for an interior visualization scene. Sometimes you need those handles... Plants, soft furniture, carpets, curtains and accessories are usually the most expensive in polycount. It's always a good idea to keep the poly count as low as possible, but you are modelling a house...

Comment: Procedural modelling is one way to decrease the file size: geonodes, subdivision modifiers, array modifiers, they won't decrease the vertex count when exporting a model to a game engine or to 3d printer or when rendering in Blender, but they will decrease the file size. Also instancing and linked duplicates can save space.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Thanks for the info. That's helpful to get a relation. I was not expecting so many polygons.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Many thanks as well for the tips. I'll take it into account.